# onClick removes ripple effect from ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a simple ImageView wrapped in a FrameLayout to give it a ripple effect:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This works perfectly fine to add a ripple effect. However when I add an onClick listener to the ImageView the ripple effect doesn't work anymore, which is odd considering the ripple effect is for elements that can be selected/clicked!

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Logic.
    }
});
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can keep the onClick and ripple?

Comment: Try to set onClickListener on parent view (FrameLayout) like this:  ((ImageView)imageView.getParent()).setOnClickListener....

Comment: @Tomislav that causes a **java.lang.ClassCastException**

Comment: Yes you are right. ImageView.getParent() is returning a ViewParent. Try this:  ((View)imageView.getParent()).setOnClickListener ... Be sure that parent View (FrameLayout) implement ViewParent interface or the cast will fall (I cannot check it now)

Comment: @Tomislav that seems to work! Add it as an answer so I can accept it :) I can just call the FrameLayout directly and add an onClick listener to that (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container).setOnClickListener...

Comment: Great. I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set onClickListener on parent view (FrameLayout) like this: `((View)imageView.getParent()).setOnClickListener...`

ImageView.getParent() is returning a ViewParent. Be sure that parent View (FrameLayout) implement ViewParent interface or the cast will fail.

Comment: Thanks! I can also directly reference the FrameLayout and add an onClick listener to that.

Comment: Yes, it is faster and cleaner way to do it